# Cause a batch file to be opened upon a file being moved to a specific file

Tags: java, c++, c, batch-file

Is it possible to cause a batch file to open and run code when a file is moved to a specific destination. Any language that this can be done in is fine, I am fairly fluent in most languages.

Eg. If i moved a file to Downloads, a notification would popup saying 'please don't move files here' and moves the file to another file.

Comment: This is an OS dependent behavior. Is this Windows, Linux, OS X ?

Comment: On Linux use inotify.

Comment: Thats the thing, i'm helping this school decide there op there gonna use and they will need a lot of file actions like this, and i was also thinking iNotify on linux, although they preferably would like to use windows.

Comment: To me, it seems key to make the solution efficient if your specification that a lot of file actions like this will occur is significant, it appears to require interactive (immediate) feedback to the user and should be light on system resources. To me that suggests a service in Windows or a daemon in Linux, for which I'd choose C++. For Windows that involves reading the journal of the filesystem or ReadDirectoryChangesW (though, be warned, the latter does miss notifications occasionally - reading the journal never misses). However, you MUST pin down the OS - there are no good portable answers

Comment: on Linux, run a 'cron' entry that triggers a bash script on a regular basis, where the script checks if the file exists at the destination. and if it does, kill the cron entry and trigger the desired executable]

Answer (score 0):

For a portable solution, your program would need to read the contents of the directory in question every X number of seconds and see if a new file appears in the listing that didn't appear the last time you checked.  If you find one, run the desired action.

Some OS's have special hooks to detect when the contents of a directory changes.  You'd need to look up the OS documentation to see how that works, and such a solution would probably require C or C++.

Answer (score 0):

Java solution would involve watching a directory for changes using [`WatchService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html).

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html for details.

> The java.nio.file package provides a file change notification API, called the Watch Service API. This API enables you to register a directory (or directories) with the watch service. When registering, you tell the service which types of events you are interested in: file creation, file deletion, or file modification. When the service detects an event of interest, it is forwarded to the registered process.

Answer (score 0):

With batch, you can do with `IF EXIST` statement of a specific file destination with in a infinite loop with `timeout` spacing.

Example:

```vb
@echo off

set "indice=filename.txt"

:loop
IF EXIST %indice% goto MyCommand

REM /T n in seconds
@timeout /T 60 /nobreak >NUL
goto loop

:MyCommand

fake-command

set /p M=job done! go to loop?(y/n):
if /I [%M:~0,1%]==[y] (goto loop) else (exit /b 0)
```